# Does tomochain RPC support eth_get_logs and eth_get_transaction_receipt?

Tags: tomochain

I'm working on the integration of Tomochain with our service. I'm wondering if these API methods are supported by Tomochain node.

```
eth_get_transaction_receipt

eth_get_logs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can get transaction receipt via TomoChain Public RPC:

```
curl --request POST   --url https://rpc.tomochain.com/getTransactionReceipt   --header 'content-type: application/json'   --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionReceipt","params":["0xe06c9409cd813cf82202cb3ebf7da2452e77dfad1c08b4e6b373924318629016"],"id":1}'
```

See the details: https://tomochain.github.io/rpc-swagger/#/eth/getTransactionReceipt